# Exporting php in a same file as html to use css (PHP issue!)

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

my name is Luis, well Im trying to make a file in html, css and php which gets information from the database and outputs it. But it has to be in the same page as the html so I can edit with CSS... thank you all!

```
<html>
<head>

</head>



<body>


<script>

</script>
<form action="<?php include 'file.php';?>" method="POST">
<b>Busque Jรก</b>
<input type="text" name="prestador" placeholder="prestador">
<input type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="cidade">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

---

File in PHP:

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$namer = $_POST['prestador'];
$cities = $_POST['cidade'];
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql = "SELECT name,address,city FROM tb_prestadores WHERE name = '$namer'   AND city = '$cities'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "name: " . $row['name']. " Endereço - : " . $row['address']." Cidade :".$row['city']."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "It is going to else";
}
 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: Refer to web basics. Including file  as an `action` value doesn't mean that this file executes when you press a button.

Comment: for a start, i'm afraid that isn't how php works... you want action to point to file.php `<form action="./file.php"...>` what you are doing there is printing the output of file.php e.g. `<form action="<?php include 'file.php';?>"` becomes `<form action="It is going to else"`

Answer (score 0):

You are including / inserting the file wrongly.

What you should do:
1) Copy your html code and paste it at the bottom of your php code i.e. after the ending '?>' tag. Your code should look like this:

```
    <?php


    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    $namer = $_POST['prestador'];
    $cities = $_POST['cidade'];
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } 

    $sql = "SELECT name,address,city FROM tb_prestadores WHERE name = '$namer'   AND city = '$cities'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "name: " . $row['name']. " Endereço - : " . $row['address']." Cidade :".$row['city']."<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "It is going to else";
    }
     $conn->close();
     ?> 

    <html>
<head>
<!-- include your css here-->
</head>



<body>


<script>

</script>
<form action="" method="POST">
<b>Busque Jรก</b>
<input type="text" name="prestador" placeholder="prestador">
<input type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="cidade">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

Btw, this is not the 'optimal' way to code applications. Please look into [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) or some other templating language as well as [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) once you get the hang of php and html basics. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your `<?php include 'file.php';?>` is miss-placed and should not be in the `action` tag of your `form` rather it should be right before it, like so:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <?php include 'file.php';?>
  <form action="" method="POST">
   <b>Busque Jรก</b>
   <input type="text" name="prestador" placeholder="prestador">
   <input type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="cidade">
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```